# Intersection of localizations of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

I have a few questions about proving the following identities:

$$\bigcap_{p \in SpecA}A_p = A \ \ \ \ \bigcup_{p \in SpecA}A_p = K$$

Here $A$ is an integral domain, $K$ is its field of fractions.
For any prime ideal $p$ we can treat $A_p$ as a subring of $K$.

My questions are:

Why does it suffice to prove the first equality only for maximal ideals? I know that maximal ideals are prime, but that doesn't help me at the moment. Of course, the inclusion $\leftarrow$ is quite obvious in case of prime ideals.

In the second equality $\subset$ is easy, because $A_p$ is a subring of $K$. A localization of a domain $A$ with respect to some multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $A$ is a subring of $K$  consisting of the elements $m/s$, with $m \in A$ and $s \in S$.

The opposite direction is troublesome.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Well, $A \subseteq \bigcap_\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \bigcap_\mathfrak{m} A_\mathfrak{m}$, so if $\bigcap_\mathfrak{m} A_\mathfrak{m} = A$ then certainly $\bigcap_\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p} = A$. This is just elementary set theory.

Comment: About the second equality: $A_{(0)}=K$, that's all. (Maybe you want to consider only non-zero primes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first equality: Note that if $p\subset m$ then by definition $A_m\subset A_p$ and $A_p\cap A_m=A_m$.

Regarding the second equality: Let $s/t\in K$. Since $A$ is an integral domain, there is a prime ideal $p$ such that $t\not\in p$ and so $s/t\in A_p$.

Comment: Oh, right. Indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one question though. Why can we find a prime ideal to which $t$ doesn't belong?

Comment: @Sasha If $t$ belongs to all prime ideals, then it is in the nilradical of your ring $A$. But $A$ is a domain, so such a nilradical is the zero ideal, hence $t=0$. This can not be (elements of $K$ are in the form $a/b$, with $a,b\in A$ and $b\neq 0$).